# How to correctly add characters to a C String in C Language?

Tags: c, fgetc

Currently I am coding a program that can go through a text file and analyze each character. If a character is alphanumeric and a valid identifier, I want to be able to add that character into a string. 
My current code to do so is this:

```
char final[256]={'\0'}; 
unsigned int len = 0;
static int current = ' ';
static int temp = ' ';

if(isalpha(current)){
   final[0]=current;
   len = 1;
   for (temp = fgetc(file); isalnum(temp) || temp == '_';){
      for(int i = len; i <= len; i++){
      final[i] = temp;
      len++;
  }
}

final[len] = '\0';
```

Am I correct to approach this problem the current way? Can you add characters to index positions of strings in C?

Comment: You can, but it's not at all clear to me why you are iterating twice.  The inner loop seems ill-formed; if both len and i are incrementing, it would seem that it will never terminate.

Comment: Well for starters you're only calling `fgetc()` once. The second `for()` will run "forever" because you're constantly increasing the condition at every iteration... basically your code is a mess.

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea; not sure if-for-for is the right approach. Should be able to do it in `O(n)`.

Comment: @Amor Diaz It is unclear what you are trying to do. Could you show an example of input data and the resulted data.

Comment: No, wait. It won't even compile because `file` wasn't initialized, and even if it was it wouldn't run because `isalpha(' ')` is 0.

Comment: The above is not the full program, only the bit that involves concatenating to a string. An example of data that it might read is "x1 := 3;", Essentially, I want my program to identify that x is alphanumeric, so it moves on to the next char that is 1 and should now be stored in final "x1". ":" should not be stored in final since it is not alphanumeric.

Comment: If you want to split your string on spaces, perhaps `strtok` is a good stuff to use

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is simple.

```
char final[256];
unsigned int len = 0;

final[len] = fgetc(file); //we read the character but do not "approve" it.
//while (!isalpha(final[len])) final[len] = fgetc(file); //uncomment if you want to read the file until a valid identifier begins. Also it's barely an example: it lacks EOF check.

if(isalpha(final[len])){
   len = 1; //We "approve" the first character
   while ( isalnum( final[len] = fgetc(file) ) || final[len] == '_') //In C, conditions are checked left to right so if isalnum()==0 we check for '_' with correctly updated final[len] value.
      len++; //We "approve" the next character;
  }
}

final[len] = 0; //The last character has been read but not "approved" so we overwrite it with null-term.
```

About the second question... yes, you can add a character to an indexed position. But it must be either last position or it'll overwrite an existing one. If you want to insert some characters, use `memmove()` function first.